# App looks black for a second before loading launcher activity. -Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a launcher activity that is simply a background so I give time for the actual activity I want to display to load all the required stuff. However, for a second or maybe less, the screen looks black before displaying the launcher background. This behavior is bothering me, how can I fix it?

Maybe this has something to the fact that the default background of my app is black? due to the android version I am working with? But I do not know.

Comment: You are probably doing too much work on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not considered good practice to use Threads for splash screens since you'll just be adding additional wait-time to the app's initial runtime (UI main thread). Instead, I'd recommend you set the splash-screen Activity to a theme as opposed to rendering a layout file since it takes time to inflate.

[This resource](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create splash screens using threads and delays, It's annoying and according to Google standars it is an anti-pattern.

I suggest you to avoid using all your thread code and even avoid using the setContentView() function by creating a drawable with the background splash image, create a new style that sets that drawable as a background and set that theme as the default theme of your SplashActivity.

Here it is all the information about the right way of creating splash screens according to Google:
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

(not my blog, just sharing the information)